# Chrome Extensions: Can I run a game on them?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, game-development

I'm looking into chrome extensions, and I was wondering if it's possible to change a specific website to add a box and run a game on it.

I believe I can change the website, no problem. But I'm having trouble figuring out what I can use to run a game in there.

Do have in mind that I'm relatively new to web dev (but not to code).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can write a game in Javascript, you can put that game into a Chrome extension.

Comment: "what I can use to run a game in there". You use the same Javascript functions you would use to run a game in a regular website.

Comment: Thanks guys. You think GWT might be a good way to go?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to manipulate pretty much anything on the website, as long as the user who installs the extension gives you permissions to inject  `content scripts` into the page. Content scripts are the Javascript and CSS files that would contain logic for your game. Once injected, you can target a DOM element in the page and initialise your game there or even create a new element and embed it somewhere in the HTML.

This is a good place to start https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: Thanks! I already got that far. But to try and inject something like a game is still something that's giving me a hard time. Meaning, I need to know in what can I develop a game to inject through a content script.